# Get The Contact Details from Lotus Notes Client Using Lotus Notes Java API?

Tags: lotus-notes

How to get the Contacts Details from Lotus Notes Client Using Lotus Notes Java API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to the "names.nsf" database and read the related view. If you check the infocenter on how to access a database in Java, it should show you some example code.

Comment: how to get the contacts using View.... for example inbox we can get like this                                                            db =  s.getDatabase("****","mail/mail1/****");
View v =  db.getView("$Inbox");                                     for Contacts which keyVaule has to pass in the getView Method?